# JQuery mobile and ASCII characters in input text

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, ascii

I have this problem in my web application developed using jQuery Mobile / PHP

- The application is intended to be used on tablet like iPad, by tablet browser
- inside my application I have a form built in jQuery mobile with some text and one text area fields
- In the text area field I need to insert also special chars that normally on desktop pc I would write using Alt+ASCII code (for example Alt+157, Alt+225, Alt+0177)
- On iPad I didn't find a way to click Alt+ASCII code on virtual tablet, so I'm thinking to add to my form some buttons, one for each special chars I need, that when clicked pass to the text area the Alt+ASCII code combination.
  Is it possible? If yes, how is it possible?
- when the form will be submitted then the content of the fields will be stored to the Mysql db... but this is not an issue

thank you very much,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem sometime back. I don't think you can rely on simulating `keypress` (which is what I think you're trying to do). `keypress` will not happen if its not trusted and specifying what key to simulating might not work on some browsers. But, here's how that's achieved.

```
$("button").click( function() {
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e.which = 50; 
  $("textarea").trigger(e);
});
```

But, this doesn't work on Chrome. So i suggest you try injecting the value through code. I setup a fiddle for you for this current situation. Here's the markup

```
 <textarea></textarea>
 <button class="special" data-char="~">Insert tilde</button>
```

and the JS

```
$(".special").click(function () {
  var char = $(this).data("char");
  $("textarea").val(function () {
      return this.value + char;
  });
```

});

and the demo 
 <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/8qs2G/</kbd>